# Clicking on a tag from the /users page should link to the list of that user's activity in that tag

Tags: feature-request, users-page

When I click on one of the top tags for the user, I expect to get that user's activity in that tag (e.g., "hacks" is one of my top tags of the week; [what did I post under that tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:23+[hacks]))

The links, instead, go to [the general tag page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacks).